# Showing that a crypto hash function is not permutation, possibly conditionally?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cryptography, jacobian-conjecture

Let $f$ be some crypto hash function, say [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) with output $n$ bits. Restrict the input to $n$ bits.
Cryptographer told me it is open problem if such restricted collision
exists, i.e. $f(x)=f(y),x \ne y$. It is widely believed they exists,
since permutations are small fraction of all functions.

> Is it possible to show for some popular hash function such collision
>   exists, possibly conditionally?

In practice $f$ is implemented as computer program or can be
represented as a boolean function or circuit.

In theory it is polynomial map $\mathbb{F}_2^n \mapsto \mathbb{F}_2^n$.

We don't have the explicit polynomials since they are expected to
be of prohibitively large degree (unless the function is heavily
backdoored), though we can compute them.

I thought about using the Jacobian conjecture in finite fields
 when having in mind $x^2 = x$ and hope that if we get zero
 determinant numerically the map is not invertible. IIRC some boolean derivatives
 can be computed in this restricted scenario, not sure if they are
 can help.

> Can the Jacobian conjecture in finite fields be used?